# How come when I divide these co-terminal angles they don't equal the same number?

Tags: trigonometry

[image: Picture from Organic Chemistry Tutor]

Source Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-xFXpVo14o

How come when I divide these co-terminal angles they don't equal the same number?
(For example, 2/3 ≠ 4/3) Is there any way I can get from one angle to another by using algebra?

Comment: Coterminal angles differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$.  Therefore, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ are not coterminal angles.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ohh! Those angles just all have the same reference angle right? That's why they're put next to each other?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  All of the angles you listed on each line have the same reference angle.